# Jquery Delay/SetTimeOut not working at all

Tags: jquery

slow function is not working. Below is the code.

```
 $('<label>Quantity'+ num + ' : </label>' + '<input type="text" name="textbox' + num + '" id="quant' + num + '" value="" >')
 .appendTo($("#"+id))
 .show('slow');
```

Comment: show() method is apply to LABEL here, not `$("#"+id)` element but it is unclear what you are asking. If you want to show `$("#"+id)`, you could use append instead: `$("#"+id).append('your ugly code for label').show('slow');`

Comment: @A.Wolff I think OP is trying to animate the newly appended element.

Comment: @rajaprabhuAravindasamy yes this is correct. I want to animate newly appended element. sorry guys just in learning stages. I will try to make it pretty. :(

Comment: @user2339193 tHEN you can use my code.

Comment: How can I make my code look better? Any good guide to coding standards?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to `hide` it first in order to `show` it with animated effect.

Try,

```
 $('<label>Quantity'+ num + ' : </label>' + '<input type="text" name="textbox' + num + '" id="quant' + num + '" value="" >')
 .appendTo($("#"+id))
 .hide()
 .show('slow');
```

Comment: @user2339193 Glad to help.! consider this answer as accepted if you wish.!